# VBA стандартная форма через макрос

Tags: excel, form, vba

Добрый день. Необходимо вызывать стандартную форму заполнения полей ( не userForm) по клику на кнопку. Не могу понять, как делается сам вызов именно обычной формы

Код вызова UserForm

```
Sub Button_calq()
ActiveSheet.Cells(11, 5).Select
UserForm.Show

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Здравствуйте!

```
Sub ShowStandartForm()
    ActiveSheet.Cells(11, 5).Select
    ActiveSheet.ShowDataForm
End Sub
```

Comment: Мне кажется странным, что имя формы нигде не используется. Ты точно правильно понял вопрос?

Comment: а какое название? это стандартная форма заполнения данных. в старых версиях Excel она вызывалась из меню "Данные"-"форма".

Comment: А.. Ой.. Это я вопрос неправильно понял.